# Modelling mongodb subcollections in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to model subcollections through C# driver, but I'm finding it difficult to do so; could you some help me to do it or some full fledged example for the same please?

I'm trying to acheive this;

```
{
id:"id", name: 'name', Tokens:[{name:"yes",expiry:'Today'}, {name:"Hello", expiry:"tomorow"}]
}
```

I have modelled a class like this

```
Class sample
{
    [BSON]
    public string id{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public TokensCollection[] tokens(get; set;} 
} 

public class TokensCollection
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string expiry{get;set;}
}
```

And in the repository I'm trying to initialize the same like this,

```
Sample sample1 = new Sample{
id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
name = "name";
//Best way to model this? any pointers?
for (int index =1; index <=2; index++)
{
    tokens[index].name = "me";
    tokens[index].expiry = "Today"
}

collection.insert(sample1);
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally answered your question on the [MongoDb CSharp Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-csharp/vxY4M9YQ2d4/UUrYvh6ogo0J) and here's the example for anyone with a similar problem;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace Test.ConsoleApp
{

public class Sample
{

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Token> Tokens { get; set; }

    public Sample()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        Tokens = new List<Token>();
    }

}

public class Token
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Expiry { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/database?safe=true");
        var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
        var samplesCollection = database.GetCollection<Sample>("samples");

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Sample #1 ... ");

        var sample1 = new Sample();
        sample1.Name = "Sample #1";
        sample1.Tokens.Add(new Token() { Name = "Name #1", Expiry = "Today" });

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Sample #2 ... ");

        var sample2 = new Sample();
        sample2.Name = "Sample #2";
        sample2.Tokens.Add(new Token() { Name = "Name #2", Expiry = "Tomorrow" });
        sample2.Tokens.Add(new Token() { Name = "Name #3", Expiry = "Next Tuesday" });

        Console.WriteLine("Saving Sample #1 and #2 ... ");

        samplesCollection.Save(sample1);
        samplesCollection.Save(sample2);

        Console.WriteLine("Fetching Sample #1 and #2 ... ");

        var sampleOneFromDb = samplesCollection.AsQueryable<Sample>().Where(c => c.Name.Contains("Sample #1"));

        Console.WriteLine("Sample #1 From DB - {0}", sampleOneFromDb.ToJson());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find the answer. I used the IList rather using Array and intialised the object like this,

there are couple of changes, in the sample class

```
   Class Sample
    {
.....

public List<TokensCollection> tokens{get; set;}
}
```

and initialized the same using

```
Sample sample1 = new Sample()
{

.....

tokens = new List<TokensCollection>{
new TokensCollection(){name='name1', expiry ='expiry1'},
new TokensCollection(){name='name2', expiry ='expiry2'}
}

}
```

It should insert your Embedded Collection document like a charm. If you want to add more docments you should use

```
tokes.add(new TokensCollection(){name='name3', expiry='expiry3})
```

all the best